# Floats wrapping "too late"

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a responsive grid of radio buttons, with a label "column" to the left of it. With the HTML and CSS below, making the window narrower eventually causes the radios to wrap to two columns, then one, as intended. However, that doesn't happen until much of their text is offscreen to the right.

It appears that the browser thinks the right-hand edge of the .controlContainer is in the wrong place, off by roughly the width of the label "column" on the left. The same behavior happens in Firefox ESR 31.4.0, Chrome 40.0.2214.115 m, and IE 11, so it doesn't seem to be a browser bug.

The sample code below includes a checkbox that applies a really funky workaround, which does work, but I hope someone can point me in a direction where that sort of nonsense isn't needed.

As noted in commented-out CSS, applying position:absolute to the .controlContainer instead of the workaround given works too, but then elements around it collapse on top of it because it takes up no space.

Note that the Run Code Snippet facility here doesn't display this correctly due to its own CSS and the restricted size of the embedded iframe, so you need to either copy the code into a local file, or [view it on CSSDeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/ixbuk1fk).

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Float wrapping</title>
  <META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    *, *:after, *:before {-moz-box-sizing: border-box; -ms-box-sizing: border-box; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;}
    body, form, pre, div, span, label {font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
    .fieldContainer {white-space: nowrap;}
    .labelContainer {display: inline-block; font-weight: bold; text-align: right; vertical-align: top; width: 150px;}
    .controlContainer {display: inline-block; max-width: 800px;}
    .controlContainer label {float: left; padding-right: 10px; width: 200px;}
    .controlGridText {display: inline-block; margin: 0 2.25em 5px 0; white-space: normal;}
    input {float: left;}
    .hackyFix .controlContainer {left: -150px; margin-left: 150px; position: relative;}
    /* .hackyFix .controlContainer {position: absolute;} can do this instead of above hack, but then other elements collapse into its space */
    /*.hackyFix .fieldContainer {overflow: hidden;} hides horizontal scrollbar, but shouldn't have to do this */
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
Make the window narrower, and eventually the radios wrap to two columns, then one.
However, that doesn't happen until much of their text is offscreen on the right.
Also note that the horizontal scrollbar appears before it's actually needed.
Check the 'Apply hacky fix' box, and the only solution I've found gets applied, but it's pretty funky, and doesn't fix the scrollbar.
See commented-out CSS for some other notes.
Better solutions are most welcome!
</pre>
<form id="form">
<hr>
<label>Apply hacky fix<input type="checkbox" id="cbHack" onclick="document.getElementById('form').className = this.checked ? 'hackyFix' : ''"></label>
<hr>
<div class="fieldContainer">
  <div class="labelContainer" style="">Favorite Lizard</div>
  <div class="controlContainer">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">1 Gecko lorem ipsum</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">2 Dolor sit amet</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">3 Iguana consectetur adipiscing elit </span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="4" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">4 Chameleon praesent scelerisque massa at placerat elementum curabitur sit amet venenatis ipsum</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="5" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">5 Morbi id elit massa</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="6" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">6 Maecenas fringilla quis odio id auctor pellentesque laoreet</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="7" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">7 Basilisk</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="8" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">8 Tuatara quam enim ornare urna</span>
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" value="9" name="r1">
      <span class="controlGridText">9 Suscipit faucibus nunc dolor vel arcu</span>
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div>This is some more text, here just to see what happens to objects below the fields.</div>
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById('cbHack').checked = false;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: checkout CSS media queries... it may do what you want it to do

Comment: Thanks ochi, but my sense is that something unexpected is happening, something I need to understand and hopefully counteract before approaching it on that level. The problem isn't that I want the layout to change with window width, it's that I want wrap behavior to match the visible situation, which it currently does not.

Answer (score 0):

[See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/qgqcjbv1/). One of the issues in the example is that it isn't using the [box model](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/) that modern frameworks are based off of, meaning that padding is getting added to the outside of elements instead of the inside. This makes percentage-based grids incredibly hard to work with if that isn't turned on.

I patched your version by including the bootstrap css but you really only need the box model to fix it. This is the other part I changed:

```
.controlContainer {
    max-width: 800px;
    width: calc(100% - 105px);
}
```

Doing this offsets the "favorite lizard" label. If I were you though, I would switch to percentage-based grids to make this a lot easier. The parent containers could have a 3 column and 9 column grid while the labels would be a 3 column grid on large, 2 on medium, and 1 on small.

Comment: Thanks Austin, the original has a box model rule, now added here and on CSSDeck, no big difference, as expected. It's the calc() rule that makes your fiddle work, not box model or bootstrap; add/remove them to prove it. Pct and calc both work perfectly, you're right. Reluctant to go w calc in a public site - old IE and mobile worries, and pct is a problem because my "users" can define label width in px outside of CSS, not a CSS problem, but real. Seems that .controlContainer needs width (not just max-width), or position: absolute. No way to keep abs from collapsing, right? Other approaches?